# Type 'string | number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement [C# Class object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) in typescript class. But compiler showing following error.

> error :  Type 'string | number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'. Error :  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'

Below is the code

```
type gender = 'Male' | 'female';

class Person {
    public name: string | null = null;
    public age: number | null = null;
    public gender: gender | null = null;

    constructor(
        param: Partial<Person>
    ) {
        if (param) {

            /**
             * Is key exist in Person
             * @param param key
             */
            const keyExists = (k: string): k is keyof Person => k in this;

            /**
             * Keys
             */
            const keys: string[] = Object.keys(param);

            keys.forEach((k: string) => {
                if (keyExists(k)) {
                    //k: "name" | "age" | "gender"

                    const value = param[k]; //value: string | number | null | undefined

                    //let a = this[k]; //a: string | number | null

                    this[k] = value; //error :  Type 'string | number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'.
                                    // Error :  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'.
                }
            });

        }
    }

}

let a = new Person({
    age: 10
});

console.log(a);
```

and below is the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
      "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
      "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
      "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
      "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
      "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is right but misleading. The problem is that `this[k]` is a union of all possible properties, so it accepts `number | string | null` but the only thing you can assign that fits into every category is `null`. It makes sense if you think of it this way `k` might be `name` or `age` - you know it's *one* but not sure which. Then `value` might be a string or a number - again, not sure which one. If `value = 42` + `k = "name"` you'll try to assign a number to a string. That doesn't work. `value = "Fred"` + `k = "age"` also doesn't work. The only type that satisfies all is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually two fold:

1. `param` is `Partial<Person>`, therefore it may not contain all the keys present. Yet, the `keyExists()` method will only inform the compiler if a given key is present in `Person`, so you will end up with `param[key]` returning `undefined`.
2. As @VLAZ has pointed out in the comments, the compiler cannot intelligently guess, or narrow the type, of `value` down to a key-by-key basis.

The solution might not be the best, but it's what that will work:

1. You need to add a type guard check if `param[k]` is undefined
2. You need to manually cast the type of `this[k]` to `typeof value`

Even though I usually avoid using manual type casting, in this case it's quite reasonable and safe, because you are, at the point of casting, working with `k` that must be a member of the `Person` class, so you are simply hinting the compiler that "I know what specific type I am working with, don't panic".

With that, the modified logic inside the `Array.prototype.forEach` callback looks like this:

```
keys.forEach((k: string) => {
  if (keyExists(k)) {
    const value = param[k];

    if (value === void 0)
      return;

    (this[k] as typeof value) = value;
  }
});
```

See it on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=13&pln=33&pc=16#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hB2ATCAnKBeKByAsgQwBsIsoAfbAMwgFtDiBuAWACgWBjAvAZy6gAVUXAPbwoAbxZQpUMAFcARgQCWbKPDzUIALihdgKJfBhk1sggQynzTZtJkLlqvHB3xZ1eahNvzlnwRs7OUUVWARkFB04JC9yfz8zAJZJaTYRPRRZNmAhFAAKFLspMDwUDR0%20UuAlQgAeARRheAA%20QqgASnE2uyUKKDySsupOiVZbIomAegAqae6JqWmoAEleAGsIECgIAA8lPShDfkEReYWlgAFBjRlSm42QM4npyae7NPgDh4BRPb1eTADO7UHQZQwwdo6a7UQ7rTZCPoNJoYZq3IaHURIkQ2N7SGZzcYLOxLADSmy4uOkL0pUA%20X3JoP04IA2gBdSwAeXkACsINkAHQPLhAobtHGEolQIX8ii5b54NgACzyeTWjIMRk66FRo0lC16-R%20f2AwrW7RGNKJdOAUAAboRZNBMNDmWtWeK9XqDXl7QRHRh0JhbUIlIgoAAGdqWz0oCDAWQoeAez1EvLARX7V3s7hQUCQBF2h0QLWFv0QQIp6QAXxpVbFyQldhrEubLCrQA).

Personally I don't like nested `if` statements because it makes the code really difficult to read, so you can also refactor the above code to use guard clauses exclusively:

```
keys.forEach((k: string) => {
  if (!keyExists(k))
    return;

  const value = param[k];

  if (value === void 0)
    return;

  (this[k] as typeof value) = value;
});
```

See on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=16&pln=24&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hB2ATCAnKBeKByAsgQwBsIsoAfbAMwgFtDiBuAWACgWBjAvAZy6gAVUXAPbwoAbxZQpUMAFcARgQCWbKPDzUIALihdgKJfBhk1sggQynzTZtJkLlqvHB3xZ1eahNvzlnwRs7OUUVWARkFB04JC9yfz8zAJZJaTYRPRRZNmAhFAAKFLspMDwUDR0%20UuAlQgAeARRheAA%20QqgASnE2uyUKKDySsupOiVZbIomAegAqae6JqWmoAEleAGsIECgIAA8lPShDfkEReYWlgAFBjRlSm42QM4npyae7NPgDh4BRPb1eTADO7UHQZQwwdo6a7UQ7rTZCPoNJoYZq3IaHURIkQ2N7SGZzcYLOxLADSmy4uOkL0pUA%20X3JoP04IA2gBdSwAeXkACsINkAHQPLhAobtHGEolQIX8ii5b54NgACzyeTWjIMRk66FRo0lC16-QAhD8-sBhWt2u0aUSUBBgLIUPBAnrJdbUulgFAAG6EWTQTDQ5lrVnil1FA15H0EP0YdCYL1CJSIKAABitErDdlt9sdoczUjywEV%20yD7O4UFAkAR3t9EC1NejEGdeoAvmLkhnpC22t2xi2gA).

Comment: `(this[k] as typeof value) = value;` ah, of cousre! I was wracking my brain trying to figure out how would you generically ensure that `value` is assignable to the property `k` but I forgot that you are already ensured compatibility from accepting a `Partial<Person>`. Therefore `value` *must* match the type for the property it was assigned to. It's just the compiler that doesn't infer that.

Comment: @VLAZ Your comment did an excellent job at explaining why `this[k]` will only accept `null` value: I am at a loss of words to explain why and your comment explained it in a way that's digestible :)

Comment: My secret is not being very good with types. So, I try to figure out the combinations. Then I realised `k = "name"`  and `value = 42` don't fit together. Yet, like the compiler I was missing the link that `value` already comes from a property with a type, so if you can't actually have that situation as `Partial<Person>` wouldn't allow you to use `{"name" : 42 }`

Comment: @Terry `(this[k] as typeof value) = value;` just worked for me. But it not the solution i am looking for. Because `undefined` is not a common type between `Partial<Person>` and `this`.

Comment: @Gyan `if (value === void 0) return;` will filter out `undefined`, so `value` cannot be that.