# VueJS Typescript v-model Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<string>'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

So I'm new to Typescript and VueJS and all of its new features.
Everything works as it is supposed to be but I cannot get rid of my typescript error and using v-model at the same time.
I'm working on a webview for a member to check and change its attributes. I get my members data from an API and store it in a PiniaStore. This means I have several InputFields requiring numbers and strings for a member. AFAIK v-model is the way to go for InputFields.

```bash
 Type 'string | number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<string>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Nullable<string>'.
```

All the suggested solutions of stackoverflow questions to this error like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948250/type-string-number-null-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-null) don't fit to my problem AFAIK. I found a bad workaround, which I don't like using a Change Event instead of v-model in my template block and having the same error in my script but ignore it via `//@ts-ignore`.

First, all I really ask for is how to comment out a typescript error in a VueJs template block, already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489659/vuejs-typescript-ignore-typescript-error-in-template-block).
Second, how do I solve this problem without having a typescript error?

Looking at the piece of code below, I have this error at `v-model` and don't know how to fix it:

```bash
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useMembershipStore } from "@/stores/membership";

const membershipStore = useMembershipStore();
membershipStore.getMembership();
const { membership } = storeToRefs(membershipStore);

function save() {
  if (membership.value) {
    membershipStore.updateMembership(membership.value);
  }
}
</script>


<template>
  <div v-if="membership === null" class="loading">
    <h2>Loading</h2>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="members-table">
    <div v-for="(value, key) in Object.keys(membership)" >
      <br />
      <InputText type="text"
        v-model="membership[value as keyof typeof membership]"
      />
    </div>
    <Button @click="save()" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here are my type definitions:
**membershipstore.ts**

```bash
export type MembershipStoreState = {
  membership: Member | null;
};
```

**types.ts**

```bash
export interface Member {
  id?: number;
  user_id?: string;
  user_attr: string | null;
  create_attr?: string | null;
  admin_attr?: string | null;
}
```

I also figured out where the type `Nullable<string>` comes from. It is from PrimeVues type definition of its component InputText, which can be found [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/4b0df651bdd724ba4c54a8c823884ed49cac7285/src/components/inputtext/InputText.d.ts#L8):

```bash
export interface InputTextProps extends InputHTMLAttributes {
    /**
     * Value of the component.
     */
    modelValue?: Nullable<string>;
}
```

Full code example can be found [here](https://github.com/MILA-Wien/collectivo-ux/blob/50dfed618a3d69a19206a14baaf4e77127519be6/src/components/extensions/membership/MembershipProfile.vue#L41)
Full code example with bad workaround using a change event, [here](https://github.com/MILA-Wien/collectivo-ux/blob/cd5f52560279a3badec7d31d0a08f4cfefe07f4f/src/components/extensions/membership/MembershipProfile.vue#L41)

Comment: erm, you don't need `Object.keys` in `v-for`, `v-for="(value, key) in membership"` should be better

Comment: True even though the code is shorter now `v-model="membership[key]"` the error still remains...

Comment: instead of commenting typescript error it is better to address it, could you show what is type definitions of `membership`. Looking from error type definition is suppose to be `string` or `null` but you are passing `number` to it?

Comment: @A.Z thanks for your suggestion! I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are defining `membership: Member|null` to check for loader `<div v-if="membership === null" class="loading">`

You can try this instead

```
export type MembershipStoreState = {
  membership: Member;
};
```

In HTML

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="Object.keys(membership).length === 0" class="loading">
    <h2>Loading</h2>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="members-table">
    <div v-for="(value, key) in membership" > // thanks to @Dimava's comment
      <br />
      <InputNumber v-if = "key === 'id' || key === 'user_id'"
        v-model="membership[key]"
      />
      <InputText type="text" v-else
        v-model="membership[key]"
      />
    </div>
    <Button @click="save()" />
  </div>
</template>
```

`Object.keys(membership).length === 0` Will check if you have popullated any of the keys of your interface otherwise it will return true and your `loading` will be visible

Comment: The error still remains at `v-model`. I implemented all of your suggestions [here](https://github.com/MILA-Wien/collectivo-ux/commit/53ee35ed160ea8e0f863cb018d8ba6f58ba6293c). I feel the problem still lies in the definition of InputText of PrimeVue only accepting strings and no numbers like an id...

Comment: I see you are disabling `:disabled="key === 'id' || key === 'user_id' || key === 'create_attr' || key === 'admin_attr'"` for numbers so what if you have a conditional `v-if` where you show `InputText` and `InputNumber` by checking `key`? Edited my answer

Comment: Thats the solution!! Typescript can tell the difference! Thanks a lot for helping me understanding typescript a little bit better!